# Domain Name Search Tool

Tags: linux, dns, search, domain-name

Is there any tool or web site that allows searching for registered and sub-domain names?

I want to find all domain names for, `*.client-channel.google.com`, `*.googleusercontent.com`, or even `*.google.com`

There is a very obvious reason for that, which I don't want to mention here. I observed that my browser has been requesting to `5.client-channel.google.com`, but I presume next time it might be `6.client-channel.google.com` or even `15.client-channel.google.com` or `25.client-channel.google.com`. That's why I need a tool to find out them all.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Only the root domain is "registered." So unless you're able to do a DNS zone transfer it's impossible to know what subdomains there are. On the other hand, if there is any reference to a subdomain on the internet you could always google for it. :)

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarification @Appleoddity, I now know what  "_registered_" domain name really is. Updated my OP to narrow down what I'm asking for.

Comment: The tool you describe doesn’t exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: It’s (generally) not possible to do this.

The only way to get a listing of all the sub-domains created under a domain is to request a [DNS zone transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer) from a primary name server that is authoritative for that domain. The primary purpose of zone transfers is to allow secondary name servers keep up–to-date with all the resource records configured on the primary name server. For security reasons, only hosts that are configured as secondary name servers for a domain are authorised to make a zone transfer from the primary name server.

If I was authorised to make a zone transfer, I could get the information you’re looking for by using the `dig` command with `AXFR` as the type of request, e.g., if Google had authorised me to make zone transfers from `ns1.google.com` (authoritative primary name server for the DNS zone responsible for `googleusercontent.com` domain), I could run the following command:

```
dig @ns1.google.com googleusercontent.com -t AXFR
```

However, since I’m not authorised, I get a *Transfer failed* response.